# Using css and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to make a fixed background changes with jQuery.
I put the style of body as follows

```
body {
  background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

Untill now everything is ok and the background is not scrolling, but when I use the jQuery to make it change it start scrolling again.

This is the jquery code :

```
$(function () {
var body = $('body');
var backgrounds = [
  'url(./images/001.jpg)', 
  'url(./images/02.jpg)','url(./images/03.jpg)','url(./images/04.jpg)','url(./images/05.jpg)'];
var current = 0;

function nextBackground() {
    body.css(
        'background',
    backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length]);

    setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
}
setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
body.css('background', backgrounds[0]);
});
```

Can any one help please?

Comment: change background image instead of background - by changing background, you are resetting a lot of the other values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit `body.css('background', backgrounds[0]);`

to
`body.css('background-image', backgrounds[0]);`

because the first code changes its entire background properties including `background-attachment`

so `background-attachment` changes backs to its default value, ie `scroll`

Comment: i found another problem that the first image is fixed , but the next images are scrolling.. any help ?

Comment: `body.css(
        'background',`

change that too to `background-image`

Comment: yeah it worked right , thanks alot ;) you'r great @Akshay

Comment: im sorry for asking alot, but can you help me making the transition by opacity ? i mean not to appear directly but something like fade in

Comment: It is really hard to fade in backgrounds @AnaSKayed you should stack divs and fade them in using jquery

Comment: No problem @AnaSKayed , glad i could help you